# How to dynamically create objects with variables?

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

I'm having trouble trying to generate objects in QML using Javascript to create them dynamically.

The code I am trying to use is this

```
Grid {
    id: numbers
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    columns: 3
    spacing: 2
    function createNumbers(){
        var component = Qt.createComponent("Button.qml");
        for(var i=1; i<37; i++){
            component.createObject(numbers)
        }
    }
    Component.onCompleted: createNumbers()
}
```

Which works fine, however I want to include variables to make them each different, so that when I pass the information to Button.qml it sets the following

```
property string text: "1"
property string id: "button1"
```

I can't figure it out, any help would be great, thanks guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qml-component.html#createObject-method)'s the documentation of method `Component.createObject`.

As you can see you can set the parameters of the new object using the second optional parameter of the function. In your case it would be:

```
component.createObject(numbers, {"text": "1", "id": "button1"});
```

Comment: Yeah literally as you typed that I'd just figured it out, thanks a lot :)